# Projection of Hypercube onto Square

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, graph-theory

Given orthogonal vectors $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^d$, is there an easy description of the hull of the projection of the d-Dimensional Cube $Q_d=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d : \|x||_\infty\leq 1\}$ onto the plane spanned by $v$ and $w$? That is, I want to find the ordered vertices of the boundary of the convex set

$${{{{
P_{v,w}Q_d=\binom{v}{w}Q_d\subset\mathbb{R}^2 
}}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Recall** that [projection operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Formulas) $\,P\,$ acting from a vector space $\,U\,$ to its subspace $\,V,\,$ spanned by orthogonal vectors $\,\vec{v}_{1},\, \ldots,\, \vec{v}_{k},\,$ [can be represented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Formulas) as a matrix composed of column vectors $\,\vec{v}_{1},\, \ldots,\, \vec{v}_{k}$ multiplied by its transpose:
\begin{align}
P:U\to V, \qquad \forall\; \vec{x} \in U \qquad 
P\,\vec{x} = AA^{T}\vec{x}, \qquad
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\big\vert & \big\vert & & \big\vert \\
\vec{v}_{1} & \vec{v}_{2} & \dots & \vec{v}_{k} \\
\big\vert & \big\vert & & \big\vert 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

You can project every vertices of $\,Q^{d}\,$ onto plane and thus get set of ordered vertices of the projection of hypercube to the plane.

Comment: The OP is looking for the vertices in the convex hull of the projection. It appears from the question that they already know how to project vectors.

Comment: @joriki Hypercube is a convex set $\implies$ its projection is also convex $\implies$ it coincides with its convex hull. Projection operator $P$ is defined on a finite-dimensional space and projects onto a plane, which is a connected subset, therefore $P$ is continuous. But then edges of hypercube are mapped by projection into connected lines $\implies$ vertices of projection are images of vertices of hypercube $\implies$ ordered vertices of a boundary of (convex hull of) projection are images of ordered vertices of hypercube excluding ones which are mapped into interior of projection.

Comment: @joriki See Corollary 1.8 [**here**](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~suvrit/teach/l1_cvxsets.pdf)

Comment: I wasn't doubting any of that (or implying that it should be explicated). I just mean that it's the part "excluding the ones which are mapped into the interior of the projection" that I believe the OP is interested in. (By the way, I don't know what you mean by "ordered vertices of the hypercube"; there's no obvious natural ordering on the vertices of the hypercube.)

Comment: My point was exactly what joriki says. How do I find out which vertices are in the 2-dimensional interior of the projection, and thus not part of the two-dimensional hull? I am also interested in a algorithmic (at best efficient) answer